# node.js - TypeError: path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to figure out what is the source of this problem. According to this [page](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html), everything should work fine, but i get this error.

```
TypeError: path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile
at ServerResponse.sendFile (/Users/apple/Documents/JavsScript/test/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:410:11)
at /Users/apple/Documents/JavsScript/test/server.js:13:9
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/apple/Documents/JavsScript/test/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at next (/Users/apple/Documents/JavsScript/test/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (/Users/apple/Documents/JavsScript/test/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/apple/Documents/JavsScript/test/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at /Users/apple/Documents/JavsScript/test/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
at Function.process_params (/Users/apple/Documents/JavsScript/test/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
at next (/Users/apple/Documents/JavsScript/test/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
at SendStream.error (/Users/apple/Documents/JavsScript/test/node_modules/serve-static/index.js:121:7)
```

Here's my code:

```
var host = '127.0.0.1';
var port = 8020;

var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'Public')))

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile('index.html');
});

app.listen(port, host, function () {
    console.log('App listening on ' + host + ':' + port);
});
```

and here's my directory structure:

```
server.js
node_modules
package.json
Public  
    views
       inde.html
```

Comment: Not sure why you're linking to the page about static resources when the error says the issue is with [`res.sendFile`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.sendFile).

Answer (score 1):

Just try this:

```
res.sendFile('Public/views/inde.html' , { root : __dirname});
```

Answer (score 0):

res.sendFile('Public/views/inde.html' , { root : __dirname}); worked for me, just wanted to give some credit!

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33095529)